# jQuery Datepicker: show current date on top / move header to top / show days of other months

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, move

I want to **customize** my datepicker. I didn't find any solution till now, so I'm asking a new question.

For now I have this scenario (simpliest datepicker):

[image: datepicker current state]

http://jsfiddle.net/w8s39/

---

I need some **modifications** just like this:
[image: desired datepicker]

1. Show current day (date and weekday) on top, right above the `table`
2. move `ui-datepicker-title` to top of the whole page - please note, there should be some html-markup between the whole datepicker-markup and the datepicker-title (the gray `divider-div`). "Prev" and "next" buttons should work
3. <strike>Show days of other months (before and after current month) in the table cells</strike>

Comment: For #3, `showOtherMonths: true`.

Comment: thanx, works excelent. I guess I didn't check documentation properly.